# Calling SQL*PLUS from UNIX Shell script and print the status message about the query

Tags: sql, unix, sh

I want to run a SQL code using shell script and return the message whether the SQL query executed successfully or not. For this I have used unix script given below.

```
#!/bin/sh          

sqlplus -S hr/hr@xe<<EOF

@emp.sql

EOF

var1=$(cat /cygdrive/d/scripts/output.txt | grep -c 'COUNT')

if [ $var1 -ge 1 ];

then

echo "success"

else

echo "failure"

fi

exit;
```

and emp.sql(called sql file) as

```
SET ECHO OFF

SPOOL D:\scripts\output.txt

SET LINESIZE 100

SET PAGESIZE 50

SELECT count(*) FROM employees;

SPOOL OFF;

EXIT 0;
```

When I execute the script I am getting output as

```
COUNT(*)
----------
   107
./script1.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

I don't know where I should put EOF statement exactly. Also I am not getting the status message whether it is success or failure which I want as output. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a bash expert, but I see an extra `;` on this line: `if [ $var1 -ge 1 ];`. Also, `exit;` followed by `and ...` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`SPOOL D:\scripts\output.txt` Isnt this windows way of referring to a file where as in the shell script you referred to the file as `/cygdrive/d/scripts/output.txt`. I assume you are using linux shell to execute so I executed your script changing the spool line in sql file. It worked fine.

Edit: Also the `\` that you used, for the spooled `output.txt` path, will cause the sqlplus to terminate. Hence the error `line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file.` Perhaps add quotes to the path or use the same file path as you used in shell

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not using linux shell. I am using Cigwin terminal in Windows which emulates unix terminal.It is working fine in PuTTY.

Comment: @user3787299 Oh, you haven't mentioned that in your question post. I haven't used Cygwin but since you are opening the sqlplus session, perhaps you shouldn't refer to the file output.txt from emp.sql outside the cygdrive mount. I have edited the answer with another observation